# Strange: Android menu icons appear only with one visible icon

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-menu

I found some strange behavior regarding android menu icons. When I add icons through onCreateOptionsMenu with

```
setVisible(false)
```

the icons will no show, and also will not appear if i call

```
setVisible(true)
```

in a later call. See my example:

```
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
  ...
  entryOne = menu.add("menuOne");
  entryOne.setIcon(...);
  entryOne.setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);
  entryOne.setVisible(false); 

  entryTwo = menu.add("menuTwo");
  entryTwo.setIcon(...);
  entryTwo.setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);
  entryTwo.setVisible(false); 

  // entryThree = menu.add("menuThree");
  // entryThree.setIcon(...);
  // entryThree.setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);
  // entryThree.setVisible(true); 

  super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}

...

public void onItemClick(...) {
...
  entryOne.setVisible(true);
  entryTwo.setVisible(true);
...
}
```

Of course I set

```
setHasOptionsMenu(true);
```

The strange thing is, that when I uncomment the last lines in *onCreateOptionsMenu* everything  is ok.

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="11"
          android:targetSdkVersion="14" />
```

Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It worked with me when i used a handler...

```
public void onItemClick(...) {
...
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            entryOne.setVisible(true);
                                     entryTwo.setVisible(true);
                        }
                    }, 100);  
...
}
```

Comment: Nope, not working here. Is it failing when you do it as I showed it in the example?

Comment: yep, before using a handler the item wont be visible..the only difference is i'm using menu.findItem(id).setVisible(true); after saving an instance of the menu..

Comment: Probably not a bug, you just need to make sure to refresh your page state.